# Need help with translation of 二つの点がちょうど目みたいに見える

Tags: grammar, meaning

My understanding is that　both みたいに and　見える means "look like" so how can they occur in the same sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-みたいに is an adjectival suffix meaning -like in the adverbial form, something close to "in a _-like way". 見える is a verb that is modified by ちょうど and 目みたいに.

> - 二つの点が:  two dots
> - ちょうど: exactly
> - 目みたいに: like eyes
> - 見える:  appear

(The) two dots look just like eyes.